# Invalid Syntax With Python Script !/usr/bin/env python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm pretty new to Python and need some help. I was trying to do this with a Raspberry Pi: http://www.muacksandglomps.com/blog/2014/04/29/pebblypi-smart-doorbell/ and I keep on getting an error when I try to compile the code. The ! in the beginning of the code is highlighted with a invalid syntax error showing. I entered my API codes in the code if this matters. Help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U need `#!/usr/bin/env python`, not `!/usr/bin/env python.`

Comment: @Joseph You should accept my answer; there is a check box next to the vote counter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you should be using is `#!/usr/bin/env python`

The #! is called a "shebang" and tells the shell which program to use to run the script.